# If I work remotely in Pakistan for Australian employer, will the embassy see it as Australian work experience while moving to Australia?

Tags: australia

I am in Pakistan right now. I need an extra 5 points to move to Australia. These points could be gained using 3 years of experience in Pakistan or by 1 year of experience in Australia. If I work remotely from Pakistan for an Australian employer, will it be called Australian experience?

Answer (score 2):

**No.** Australian work experience can only be gained by legally working in Australia for an entity with an Australian business number (ABN/ACN) and having the Australian tax records to prove it.

Can your Australian company sponsor you to come to Australia on a 457 visa? Then you wouldn't need to worry about points anymore.

Comment: There is no company offering me a job from Australia yet. I will start searching.